# Get date from specific timezone - C

Tags: c, date, time, timezone

I need to get the date/time from a specific timezone **without** setting the `TZ` variable.

 I tried to use the `gmtime` and plus to the hour the difference, the issue I got with this method, is that time variations, for example, the daylight, or the day difference between China/Usa caused by the hour, I need to handle all of that, is there any way/library or whatever I can use for get an specific timezone with that variations included?

I am using win32, It would be better if it works with everything. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the initial value of `TZ`, get the time, and then reset `TZ`?

Comment: gettimeofday() takes struct timezone * as additional parameter

Comment: @raptortech97 I'm having some troubles with TZ, the `setenv` and the `tzset` can't be find (I already search in many libraries), I think it is because I'm under windows 7 (win32)

Comment: One downsize of changing TZ sets it for the entire process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this (if I'm understanding your requirement correctly) is to use the Olson/IANA TZ database.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) points to the [IANA sources](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Using this library isn't a one-liner (though depending on your platform, the library may be already installed or be easily-installable).  However (a) it's the Right Thing To Do, (b) it's as robust and accurate as anything else you're likely to find, and (c) it's well enough known that I expect you'll have little difficulty in googling for information and tutorials about it, should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`localtime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) will work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but that gets the time of the timezone that your computer is using, what I'm talking about, it's how to get for example the timezone of United States, China and GMT+5 for example.

Comment: @Spamdark - Oh, ok, I thought you ment from where the code was being run from (local computer), not that you'd pick them.. sorry. I'll see whatelse I can think of.

Comment: Yup, I mean, get the time at United States setting the timezone for example (I wrote get the timezone...)